# Console input redirect

Tags: c#, .net, process, console

I am writing a windows application that emulates the console by redirecting input and output of the cmd.exe to a text box. The starting code is below:

```
StreamWriter inputWriter;
StreamReader outputReader;
StreamReader errorReader;
Process proc = new Process();
byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] errorBuffer = new byte[1024];

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Q";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
inputWriter = proc.StandardInput;
outputReader = proc.StandardOutput;
errorReader = proc.StandardError;
outputReader.BaseStream.BeginRead(outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.Length, ShowOutput, null);
errorReader.BaseStream.BeginRead(errorBuffer, 0, errorBuffer.Length, ShowError, null);proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Q";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
inputWriter = proc.StandardInput;
outputReader = proc.StandardOutput;
errorReader = proc.StandardError;
outputReader.BaseStream.BeginRead(outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.Length, ShowOutput, null);
errorReader.BaseStream.BeginRead(errorBuffer, 0, errorBuffer.Length, ShowError, null);
```

When I start the proces I am able to read the console output and also to send the commands to it by writing to the input stream.

When I start some application this way the output of that application is also being redirected and everything still works fine, but the application doesn't seem to receive the data that is being written to the input stream. Even some console commands can't receive the input.
e.g. If i call `inputWriter.WriteLine("del *.log");` I receive the "Are you sure" prompt but when i call `inputWriter.Write("y");` "y" is echoed back by the console but nothing happens, the console continues to wait for input.
If i call `inputWriter.WriteLine("pause");` console pauses and after `inputWriter.Write(" ");` it continues just like it should.

What is the problem here and how can I correctly redirect the input to both the console and the application (and command) that is being executed within it?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem, it might be related to the way the win32 command interpreter treats input for security reasons. There are a couple of projects out there that have solved the issues (mostly), such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/). You might want to look through the code (it's C++ though) to try to figure out if there are tricks you need to implement to get around the input restrictions (if they are indeed to blame).

I don't think I've ever seen a full console replacement solution written in C#.

Comment: The closest think to console replacement I've seen is POSH Console. And yes, I don't know the details, but console programming is clunky and even Powershell has a few limitation because of the way windows console works.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this on multiple occasions. The problem is caused because your program is single threaded. You need to run the process asyc. Here is an exmample I have.

```
 private void exportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        p.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        //p.WaitForExit();
        //p.Dispose();
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox(String message)
    {
        if (consoleOutputBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            UpdateConsoleWindowDelegate update = new UpdateConsoleWindowDelegate(UpdateTextBox);
            consoleOutputBox.BeginInvoke(update, message);
        }
        else
        {
            consoleOutputBox.AppendText(message);
        }
    }

    void ConsoleOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs recieved)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(recieved.Data))
        {
            UpdateTextBox(recieved.Data + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually i have made id async using BeginRead on the output stream. Writing to the input stream causes the problem when the console (or a program running in the console) is waiting for input.
I can run commands such as dir, cd etc. but once a prompt is needed (such as y/n) the console does not respond to the characters that are written to the input stream.
Seems that somehow I must find a process executed by the console (if there is one) and then write into that process' input stream...